# Clearcase: how can I obtain file information given the VOB source container path

Tags: clearcase

My application receives a clearcase source container path (from a snapshot view) like this: **\hostmachine\vobs\VOBNAME.vbs\c\cdft\1e\1d\92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3**

Assuming I know the type of document (PDF, Word, Excel, Text etc), I can open this path with its associated application. But how do I obtain the file type from this path?

I know that the original file name can be gotten using cleartool desc command:

**cleartool desc oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3**

but this only works if I set my working directory to the view containing the VOB. Since all I have is the source container path - I don't know what view it came from. Is there any way to obtain the original name of the file using this path without knowing the path of the view?

Alternatively, is there a simple way to determine which snapshot view contains this path?

Answer (score 1):

This [old thread (2006)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=104200) mentions trying a `cleartool dump`.
I know it is executing in a view, but it might be worth it to try it in *any* of your dynamic views, just to see if it might still work.

```
2027]dilip@sun3> ct pwv ; pwd ; ls
Working directory view: ** NONE **
Set view: 2.dilip

/vob_store/TEST_VOB.vbs/c/cdft/32/14

1c194c97205e4d25bb1d6e2053e4c27a a28b1e28b23342b3a4fd507703dbfc7f
edbf360518b040339038399b7a0479a1
419e3e622be2474bbe3fd52925a3273d c63ab80cf44711d98ee0000d9d4a0e31

2029dilip@sun123> ct dump oid:a28b1e28b23342b3a4fd507703dbfc7f*
@/vobs/TEST_VOB*

oid:a28b1e28b23342b3a4fd507703dbfc7f@/vobs/TEST_VOB
/vobs/TEST_VOB/docs/helle.c@@/main/1
oid=a28b1e28.b23342b3.a4fd.50:77:03:db:fc:7f dbid=15385 (0x3c19)
mtype=version
stored fstat:
```

Comment: Dynamic views are not a problem for me because clearcase gives me a path that includes the file name. I tried ct dump oid:a28b1e28b23342b3a4fd507703dbfc7f@/vobs/TEST_VOB as you suggested but it didn't give any information about the file name.

Comment: @yitz: any chance to repeat that command in a dynamic view? (any dynamic view)? What kind of information did it gave you? If that dynamic view has the `TEST_VOB` mounted (even if the config spec of said dynamic view has *nothing* to do with `TEST_VOB`), it **will give you the path**. I just tested it. It works.

Comment: @yitz: I just tested the `dump` command in a **snapshot** view (which had nothing to do with `TEST_VOB`)... and it worked too! It gave me the path!

Comment: When I run the command in a snapshot view that contains the correct VOB, I get the file name. But if I 'cd' to a view that does not have that VOB then I don't get the filename.

Comment: This is the output I get (names of VOBS etc. have been changed to protect company privacy)
  
cleartool> **dump oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@\MYVOB**

oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@\MYVOB
**C:\CCViews\MYVIEW\MYVOB\docs\MYDOC_DP.xls@@\main\mybranch\8**
oid=92a7e128.6af94895.95a9.df:22:07:30:e1:e3  dbid=18127 (0x46cf)
mtype=version
...

cleartool> **cd C:\CCViews\AnotherView**
cleartool> dump oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@\MYVOB

oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@\MYVOB
oid=92a7e128.6af94895.95a9.df:22:07:30:e1:e3  dbid=18127 (0x46cf)
...
cleartool>

Comment: @yitz: I get a path in both cases (just tested it in a basic snapshot view, with a simple `element * main/LATEST rule`): works every time (I get an extended path). Any chance you can do it in a snapshot view with the Vob in it (even if that Vob is just in `main/LATEST`)?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to work in a view that contains that Vob but I'm working on a general utility and I don't know which views the user has that contains the correct VOB.

Comment: @yitz But you don't need to know the view! Just use a simple basic snapshot view, click into the Vob, and do your dump in there.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I don't control which views the user has and I don't want to have to dynamically create one for this tool

Comment: @yitz: couldn't create just one dynamic view, that the user would be able to start (through your script), mount the right Vob and use for that dump? Or must that tool always runs within an existing user snapshot view?

Comment: The tool cannot create or delete any views - only read existing information.

Comment: @yitz: it doesn't need to create one, only to start an *existing* one, dedicated for making dumps. That's why I proposed to create now a dedicated dynamic view, to be reused later by your script (which would only start the view, not create or delete anything). That dynamic view would be reuse by your script for any user and any Vob.

Answer (score 0):

There is sufficient documentation for this, but it isn't quite obvious to connect the dots to solve your problem, see:

```
cleartool man fmt_ccase
```

Notice the %Xn and %n specifiers, which means you can do:

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%Xn\n" oid:<oid-str>@<vob-prefix>
```

For example:

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%Xn\n" oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@\MYVOB
```

or

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%Xn\n" oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@/vobs/MYVOB
```

or

```
cleartool desc -fmt "%Xn\n" oid:92a7e1286af9489595a9df220730e1e3@@vobuuid:<vob-oid>
```

But keep in mind that strictly speaking, it isn't possible to get the element path portion of the file/version without a view context due to XPN paths being inherently ambiguous (many possible "evil twin" scenarios)--so you either need to establish a view context with the same view where the file/version of interest was accessed, or you need to create your own dedicated view with the same config-spec to use with the commands above.